# xpath to get two entries

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an xml with several entries as follows (along with other tags as well)

```
    <entry>
        <id>
            https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/14sCud5RqFt7O44Ol_GnTBgwFbZSnWAW-dJ833ryfWY8/1/private/full/R4C3
        </id>
        <updated>2015-12-02T05:49:20.867Z</updated>
    </entry>
<entry>
        <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/14sCud5RqFt7O44Ol_GnTBgwFbZSnWAW-dJ833ryfWY8/1/private/full/R3C2
        </id>
        <updated>2015-12-02T05:49:20.867Z</updated>
</entry>
```

I would like to get first two `<entry>` tags using a single xpath expression. Can I do this using xpath? If so how.

Comment: can you paste a longer example with several `<entry>` elements? are they siblings (at the same level in the tree)? or do the first 2 have different parent elements?

Comment: the entry elements are at the same level--they are siblings

Comment: ok, so @Dmytro's answer would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this.

```
//entry[position()<3]
```